# Shouldn't Redux prevent re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a `List` component that displays multiple `Item` components. `List` gets its data from the Redux store.

When the store is updated (because I deleted an item for example), all `Item`s are re-rerendered. **Why is that?**

I know I could use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to prevent a new rendering, but I thought Redux would do it internally.

List.js

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Item from './Item';

class List extends Component {
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>List</h2>
        {items.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} name={item.name} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  items: state.items
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(List);
```

Item.js

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Render', this.props.name); // The component is re-rendered even if the props didn't change
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Item.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};

export default Item;
```

Comment: Because you have a new array items in props.

Comment: @Andrew I get that `List` is re-renreded, because the `items` prop is updated. But what about `Item`? Its props didn't change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit of prior art (as Dan Abramov likes to say): Redux is a state management tool. It provides a HOC (`connect`), but that HOC is *not responsible for component management*. Redux does not manage your component's lifecycle in anyway: it provides a means to efficiently store and query data your app needs. It's largely influenced by the Om, a Clojurescript bridge to React. In fact, `store`s in redux very much resemble the `atom` data type in Clojure.

Now, getting into the meat of your problem -- even if your data is *exactly* the same, and even if you did use `shouldComponentUpdate`, your component is still going to re-render. The reason is that `Array.prototype.map` *always* produces a new object on the heap. As a result they're not *referentially equal*. Some code to demonstrate this concept:

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3]
const myArrCopy = myArr.map((n) => n);
myArr === myArrCopy // false
```

But if we use `shallowEqual`, we get a different result:

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3]
const myArrCopy = myArr.map((n) => n);
React.addons.shallowCompare(myArr, myArrCopy); // true
```

Why is that? That's because `shallowCompare` checks for *value equality*, comparing each value in the arrays. However, `shallowEquals` contains a potential pitfall for the uninitiated:

```
const myObject = { foo: 'bar' };
const myObject2 = { foo: 'baar' };
React.addons.shallowCompare(myObject, myObject2); // true
```

Our two objects aren't the same, but `shallowCompare` returns `true` because it only compares the *keys* of its arguments. If that's good enough for you, you can simply extend `React.PureComponent`, which implements `shouldComponentUpdate` for you, and uses `shallowCompare` to compute equality of `props` and `state`.

Enter [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). This does away with the need for `shallowCompare` entirely. Consider the following:

```
const myList = Immutable.List([1, 2, 3]);
const myListCopy = myList.map((n) => n);
myList.equals(myListCopy) // true
```

Internally, Immutable shares data, and can very efficiently compare data structures for deep equality. That being said, Immutable comes with trade-offs: data structures become much more opaque and can be more difficult to debug. All in all, I hope this answers your question. JSBin here: https://jsbin.com/suhujalovi/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: What about the fact that reducers are pure functions in Redux? Does it bring any performance benefit over Flux? (I thought it would prevent unnecessary renderings)

Comment: You can make _any_ function a pure function. As long as the function's 'dependencies' are _exclusively_ its arguments. Redux reduces a lot of the boilerplate that came with Flux; that's why it's now the de-facto standard for production React apps. The pure fact of a function being pure doesn't guarantee efficiency. So, tldr, Redux doesn't bring performance benefits out of the box. Managing renders/lifecycle is still your responsibility.

Comment: Ok, so switching from Flux to Redux to "solve performance issues", might not be **the** solution.

Comment: No, it isn't. There are no silver bullets in software engineering. But that being said, Redux makes it a heck of a lot easier to solve performance issues, because it's much easier to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` if your reducers are pure.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all your answers. It really helped me

Comment: Thanks. If my answer helped, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it as the answer to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137164/discussion-between-jmaylin-and-natnai).

Comment: Great answer from @natnai.  If you'd like more info, I described some of the key concerns for Redux performance in this blog post : http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/ .

Answer (score 1):

```
{items.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} name={item.name} />)}
```

This line make always a new Array in the parent component, producing 'new' Item components every time

Comment: So what would be the solution? Should I directly connect `Item` to the store?

Comment: I prefefr the 'shouldComponentUpdate' approach :)

Comment: Damn. I thought that one of the main benefits of using Redux (and its non-mutating reducers) over Flux was to avoid this issue :/

Comment: I have used flux 1 year ago, and now I use redux, for me, the main benefit is 'organization' and 'scalling', flux starts to be a mess when you cant see main state application centralize in one place instead of spread in many stores

Comment: I agree on this point, but I thought there would also be performance benefits.