# Prevent re-rendering of array mapped components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native, redux

**Problem**

Every time I dispatch an action (ex. TOGGLE_TODO), the array re-renders even though only one of the state values changed

**Code**

List rendering

```
{
    arr.length > 0 ?
        arr.map(({ id, text } = {}) => {
            return (
                <TaskElement key={id}
                    text={text}
                    toggleTask={() => toggleTask(id)}
                    removeTask={() => removeTask(id)} />
            )
        }) :
        // ...
}
```

Reducer

```
...
case 'TOGGLE_TASK':
        return state.map(task => (
            task.id === action.id ? {
                ...task,
                checked: !task.checked
            } : task
        ))
...
```

When I toggle a task there is a visible delay between updates. I've tried to fix this by making the `TaskElement` a PureComponent and even wrote my own `shouldComponentUpdate` using shallow equality but it still re-renders.

I am aware that mapping an array creates a completely new one in memory which invalidates the key prop causing the re-render. Is there any way to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT
Similiar question : [Shouldn't Redux prevent re-rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579559/shouldnt-redux-prevent-re-rendering)

Comment: implement shouldComponentUpdate  on parent component not on TaskElement , but the better way is to use FlatList instead of map

Comment: Just because it is rerendered in react doesn't mean it will rerender the DOM which is slow. Measure your app performance. Don't try to guess where it is slow.

Comment: Since action works, the state will always change. It is how reducer works

Comment: @Wolverine Did what you said and no change.

Comment: @evolutionxbox How would you recommend I do that? (Does console logging in the render method mean it was pushed to the DOM)

Answer (score 0):

Keep/Make the TaskElement as PureComponent.

Inside the Reducer, only update the array item which requires a change.

Reducer

```
...
case 'TOGGLE_TASK':
        let stateCopy = [...state];
        const toggledItemIndex = state.findIndex((task) => task.id === action.id);

        stateCopy[toggledItemIndex] = {
        ...stateCopy[toggledItemIndex],
        checked: !stateCopy[toggledItemIndex].checked,
        };

        return stateCopy;
...
```

Comment: Tried it in production mode and it starts to slow down after around 20 elements.

Comment: You should post a separate question to get a solution to optimise the performance impact due to additional tasks. You would also need to share the relevant operation (code) which degrades the performance .