# Why are all the PureComponent children of a container updating when only one child's state is modified in the container's state tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Learning React and Redux. I'm playing with the Redux examples, and currently looking at the [todo-with-undo](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/ecb1bb453a60408543f5760bba0aa4c767650ba2/examples/todos-with-undo) example (don't think its possible to set up a sandbox or something). In this setup there is a container component (TodoList) and it's children (Todo).

I modified the Todo from a functional component to PureComponent class so that shouldComponentUpdate() returns false if all the prop references are the same, and thus the components shouldn't update (but they will still re-render???).

Adding code to log when a child updates with componentDidUpdate() method and also to log when re-rendering shows that every time a new Todo is added to the container, **all elements update and rerender** - even whilst being PureComponents - it should be the case that shallow comparisons of old and new props for each child should return false for the new or updated child.

Being an example built by Redux I doubt that they update the store incorrectly (not in an immutable fashion), as that is the point of their concept, so I believe I am not fully understanding something -> someone please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `<TodoList>` is passing a new callback function reference to each child:

```js
export default class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.todos.map((todo, index) =>
          <Todo {...todo}
                key={index}
                onClick={() => this.props.onTodoClick(index)} />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

That will always cause the child to re-render, even if it's attempting to optimize renders based on props comparisons.

Comment: ...because it generates new function objects every time, didn't think about this, cheers for the answer.

Comment: Sure. For more details, see my extensive post on [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/).

Answer (score 0):

PureComponent does not mean it will not update, it just mean React will handle comparison of props and state for you by implementing shouldComponentUpdate with shallow prop and state comparison.

Comment: I understand, I should have been clearer, however the shallow comparisons should return true for all but the updated or new child - I didn't implement the reducers (state updates) that control this, the redux developers did, so it should be fine.

Comment: look at this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579559/shouldnt-redux-prevent-re-rendering

Comment: cheers, the link helped with my understanding of how PureComponents implement shouldComponentUpdate(), however I don't think it helps the situation. In todo demo,  TodoList gets an array of strings. The reference of the array changes with e.g. new todo (immutability), so TodoList rerenders, okay. This leads to update checking for children, only prop given is a string (primitive in JS), and react shallow comparison compares old and new values of these directly?, so should return false if unchanged? I think this is correct, but it still doesn't align with the app behaviour, so...

Comment: when you toggle todo you are creating a new todo array using map, that's what cause re-render, you should use React.memo to prevent todo update,

look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/todos-with-undo-e049t

Comment: React.memo and functional components are exactly what I need, and really thank you for helping my understanding, but still no idea why PureComponent shouldn't work. I get that the map function will give a new array with new reference, TodoList will re-render, and induce updating of children, but the children are just given strings, and if they are the same strings as before, shouldComponentUpdate() should return false right? I will read more and maybe something will click.

Comment: it's not a sting, Redux pass new array to the TodoList component, and creating a new Todo. it javascript not react, you need to use Memo or shouldComponentUpdate to prevent re-render

Comment: Array of strings for TodoList, but it is strings for its Todo children, the children receive the 'text' prop, and they determine whether they need to update best on their props, which is text (if they are Pure, or functional and using mimo).